# Extracting json data in Clover ETL

Tags: json, cloveretl

How do I extract JSON values along with keys using Xpath in Clover ETL`{"code": "in","percent": 83}`? 
Eg :-.
For the JSON object in the example I don't want just values i.e [in,83] 
I also want keys with them i.e `["code": in,"percent": 83]`

Comment: Please show us some code of what you have tried so far and provide some example data.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for "decode(name())" function of XPath.

There is an example in the documentation https://doc.cloverdx.com/documentation/UserGuide/topic/com.cloveretl.gui.docs/docs/jsonreader.html (search "name()") which is doing what you need.